# How to pass page title to views through controller in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-controller

I'm trying to dynamically pass each page title to views via the controller. I have included the page header inside the views/components folder and passing it to each view as `<x-header></x-header>`. Then in the header  tag I'm trying to echo the page title as {{$title}}, but I get the error "Undefined variable $title". How to debug this error?

Controller

```
public function index() {
    $title = "Home || My site";
    return view('home', compact('title'));
}
```

header.blade.php file in components/header

```
<head>     
    <title>
        {{ $title }}
    </title>
</head>
```

home.blade.php view with header included on top

```
<x-header></x-header>
<div class="search-relative search-relatives " id="search-relatives">
<div class="item height25vh" id="vid">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your components attribute correctly

```
<x-header :title=$title></x-header>
```

I assume you already setup your header.php file

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-components)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<x-header>{{ $title ?: 'Default Value' }}</x-header>
```